# callback is not a function but script works

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Hello I have a problem with this code

```
const lineReplace = require('line-replace')

lineReplace({
  file: 'outputfinal.txt',
  line: 4,
  text: '',
  addNewLine: false,
  onReplace
})

function onReplace({file, line, text, replacedText}) {

}
```

The script remove the line 4, so the script works. But it returns an error that stops execution of the script.

```
      callback({file, line, replacedText, text})
      ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Niiky\Desktop\node_modules\[4mline-replace[24m\src\line-replace.js:38:7)
[90m    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)[39m
[90m    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:210:5)[39m
[90m    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:666:14)[39m
[90m    at _stream_writable.js:643:7[39m
[90m    at WriteStream._final (internal/fs/streams.js:297:3)[39m
[90m    at callFinal (_stream_writable.js:636:10)[39m
[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)[39m
```

Why I'm getting this error and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [documentation](https://github.com/codealchemist/line-replace) is wrong/misleading.  It seems to want the callback you pass in to be a property named `callback`, not `onReplace`:

```
const lineReplace = require('line-replace')

lineReplace({
  file: 'outputfinal.txt',
  line: 4,
  text: '',
  addNewLine: false,
  callback: onReplace   // this argument apparently needs to be a property named callback    
})

function onReplace({file, line, text, replacedText}) {

}
```

In questions like this, particular with a fairly simple module like this, just go look up [the source](https://github.com/codealchemist/line-replace/blob/master/src/line-replace.js#L38) and see what it's doing.

Slight warning.  While this library uses asynchronous streams for reading/writing the file, it uses synchronous I/O for renaming/deleting the temporary file.  As such, it shouldn't be used in a server context without fixing that in the library.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer, review the code and create the issue!
You're right about the sync calls to FS, so I just removed them and published v2.
https://github.com/codealchemist/line-replace

Hope this helps.
Cheers!